# Insert documents with random data in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Goog morning.

I am trying to code some scripts to insert documents in a collection in MongoDB. The problem is that I need the data to be random. This is my code:

```
async function run(service) {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db("myDb");
    const collection = database.collection("myEvents");
    // create a filter to update all movies filtering the service
    const filter = { service: service };
    const updateDoc = {
        $set: {
          idIn: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1) + 5, 
          idOut: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
        },
    };

    const result = await collection.updateMany(filter, updateDoc);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
let service = readline.question("Insert an id: ");
run(service).catch(console.dir);
```

Here the data is created once and then updates all the documents in the collection with the same values. I need to update every document with two different (IdIn and IdOut) values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how a random number is generated. If all numbers are based in the same seed, all will be the same.

So you haveto use `forEach()` to iterate over the collection and adding values, then, the seed is not the same for all values.

Note that `forEach` is not the same using `mongoose` and `mongo`. Using `mongo` you can do `collection.find().forEach(...)`.

Using `mongoose` is in this way:

```js
model.find({}).then(doc => 
  doc.forEach(element => {
    element.idIn = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1) + 5
    element.idOut = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    element.save()
  }))
```

The `find` query is empty because you want to update every document. With the values returned by the query (all documents), you can iterate one by one using `forEach`, and calculate a random number for each one and adding to value.
And after that save the document into collection.